# Is there a Simple Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, teaching-method, linguistics

For english, a simple version of the language, called *[Simple English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_English)* has been defined — an english-based [controlled language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_natural_language) — as an aid to teaching english to non-native speakers.
Has it ever been an effort by someone to do the same with latin, and create a *Simple Latin*?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latino_sine_flexione ?

Comment: Am not so sure about *Latino sine flexione*. Simple English is still English. Latino sine flexione looks like Latin's pidgin. I was rather looking for a *Core Latin* with a core vocabulary, and simplified syntax, ex. subject-object-verb only, but all necessary inflection to make it latin would be there

Comment: Simple English is useful because knowing it helps people communicate and understand one another, but people typically learn Latin to engage with the existing Latin literature (with communication as a fun side-effect). I can't see what the point would be. An individual course will employ restricted grammars/vocabulary lists as the course progresses but that isn't really the same thing.

Comment: I believe the Latin of [Ritchie's Fabulae Faciles](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/ritchie.html) is a sort of controlled language with a limited vocabulary and grammar. It gets more complex as the book runs on, but at the beginning, for example, the subjunctive is not used, with the consequence that it uses *ubi* instead of *cum* all over the place, which is not very idiomatic but "correct" Latin.